# autocomplete address form cross two tables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

newbie here, and need help.

I use the codes from http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/29/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-php-and-mysql/

and it works just fine for some fields. My problems are that I have countries and states stored in another table, and I got "Trying to get property of non-object" error around "if ($address_query->num_rows) {".

The autocomplete.php

```
$dbhost = 'SERVER';
$dbuser = 'USERNAME';
$dbpass = 'PASSWORD';
$dbname = 'DATABASE_NAME';

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$return_arr = array();
if ($conn)
{
$ac_term = "%".$_GET['term']."%";
$address_query = "SELECT * FROM address where customer_id = '" . $customer_id . "' AND (firstname like :term OR lastname like :term) LIMIT 10";
if ($address_query->num_rows) { // got "Trying to get property of non-object" error
        $country_query = "SELECT * FROM country WHERE country_id = '" . (int)$address_query->row['country_id'] . "'";

if ($country_query->num_rows) {
            $country = $country_query->row['name'];
            $iso_code_2 = $country_query->row['iso_code_2'];
        } else {
            $country = '';
            $iso_code_2 = '';
        }

        $zone_query = "SELECT * FROM zone WHERE zone_id = '" . (int)$address_query->row['zone_id'] . "'";

        if ($zone_query->num_rows) {
            $zone = $zone_query->row['name'];
            $zone_code = $zone_query->row['code'];
        } else {
            $zone = '';
            $zone_code = '';
        }   
$result = $conn->prepare($address_query);
$result->bindValue(":term",$ac_term);
$result->execute();

/* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $return_arr [] = array(

    'label' => $row['firstname'] .' '. $row['lastname'] .' '. $row['company'] .' '.         $row['city'] .' '. $row['postcode'],
  'value' => $row['firstname'] .' '. $row['lastname'],
  'Company' => $row['company'],
  'Country' => $row['iso_code_2'],
  'postCode' => $row['postcode'],

   );
}


}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
flush();
?>
```

If I remove the codes

```
if ($query->num_rows) { // got "Trying to get property of non-object" error
        $country_query = "SELECT * FROM country WHERE country_id = '" . (int)$address_query->row['country_id'] . "'";

if ($country_query->num_rows) {
            $country = $country_query->row['name'];
            $iso_code_2 = $country_query->row['iso_code_2'];
        } else {
            $country = '';
            $iso_code_2 = '';
        }

        $zone_query = "SELECT * FROM zone WHERE zone_id = '" . (int)$address_query->row['zone_id'] . "'";

        if ($zone_query->num_rows) {
            $zone = $zone_query->row['name'];
            $zone_code = $zone_query->row['code'];
        } else {
            $zone = '';
            $zone_code = '';
        }
```

it works for name, company and postcode. BTW, the country and state fields are dropdown select form.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `$address_query` is just an sql string not an object, you can't get a property out of a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your $address_query is not an object but a string so you get the error "Trying to get property of non-object"

To access the pdo object you need to access it through $conn you created

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);

$address_query = "SELECT * FROM address where customer_id = '" . $customer_id . "' AND (firstname like :term OR lastname like :term) LIMIT 10";

$result = $conn->prepare($address_query);
$result->execute(array(':term'-> $term)); 

if ($result->rowCount()){
```

the $conn is the object and the $address_query is the string, also in your string you have a place holder :term you need to set that value for your sql statement in the execute function, this is find all :term in the string and replace them with the value

also your sql is out of wack since you have know country id in the table you should join the tables

your code should look something like this :

```
$dbhost = 'SERVER';
$dbuser = 'USERNAME';
$dbpass = 'PASSWORD';
$dbname = 'DATABASE_NAME';

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$return_arr = array();
if ($conn)
{
$ac_term = "%".$_GET['term']."%";
$address_query = "SELECT * FROM address LEFT JOIN country address.country_id = country. country_id ON where address.customer_id = '" . $customer_id . "' AND (address.firstname like :term OR address.lastname like :term) LIMIT 10";

$result = $conn->prepare($address_query);
$result->bindValue(":term",$ac_term);
$result->execute();

/* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $return_arr [] = array(

    'label' => $row['firstname'] .' '. $row['lastname'] .' '. $row['company'] .' '.         $row['city'] .' '. $row['postcode'],
  'value' => $row['firstname'] .' '. $row['lastname'],
  'Company' => $row['company'],
  'Country' => $row['iso_code_2'],
  'postCode' => $row['postcode'],

   );
}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The error message is gone, but json return do data, [].

Comment: That is not the problem you asked about, but confirm that your sql is returning data or that you $return_arr has something in it, print_r($result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) or print_r($return_arr)

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I changed the line to

```
$address_query = "SELECT * 
FROM address 
LEFT JOIN country 
ON address.country_id = country.country_id 
where address.customer_id = '" . $customer_id . "' AND (address.firstname like :term OR address.lastname like :term) LIMIT 10";
```

Thanks to all who helped me.